# Reportlab's Grid looking completely off

Tags: python, reportlab

It looks like my table content and grid are not behaving properly, i.e. the grid is not boxing in the data as it is supposed to.

This is my code:

```
    story = []

    data = [['Data1', 'Data2', 'Data3', 'Data4', 'Data5', 'Data6'],
            ['0.2', '-0.1', '0', '0', '-0.5', '0.6']]

    colwidths = (50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50)
    rowheights = (10, 10)

    t = Table(data, colwidths, rowheights)

    GRID_STYLE = TableStyle(
        [('FONTSIZE', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 5),
         ('GRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.5, colors.black),
         ('ALIGN', (1, 1), (-1, -1), 'RIGHT')]
    )

    t.setStyle(GRID_STYLE)
    story.append(t)

    doc = SimpleDocTemplate('mydoc.pdf', pagesize=landscape(letter), topMargin=50)
    doc.build(story)
```

and this is the pdf output I am getting:

[image]

Does anyone know what I am overlooking here?

Comment: Remove the rowheights and it works. I do not know why.

Comment: Thanks. However, I would like to keep the rowheights specified - the height are just too big otherwise.

Comment: playing around with it, it seems 15 is about the lowest height you can go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to your Align (1,1), (-1,-1), which Right Align from Column 1, Row 1 (and not Column 0 and Row 0 (counting starts at 0)), in my experience it is all about being verbose when specifying the TableStyle. If you don't, the Style will itself assign default values (such as right and left padding) which often is not what you are looking for. So, for full control, try to assign a value to all categories and don't leave any relevant category out.

E.g. I got it to look better with below

```
story = []

data = [['Data1', 'Data2', 'Data3', 'Data4', 'Data5', 'Data6'],
        ['0.2', '-0.1', '0', '0', '-0.5', '0.6']]

colwidths = (50)
rowheights = (10)

t = Table(data, colwidths, rowheights)

GRID_STYLE = TableStyle(
    [('FONTSIZE', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 5),
     ('GRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.5, colors.black),
     ('ALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'CENTER'),
     ('LEFTPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0),
     ('RIGHTPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0),
     ('TOPPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0),
     ('BOTTOMPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0),
     ('FONTNAME', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'Helvetica'),
     ('SIZE', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 7),
     ('LEADING', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 8.2),
     ]
)

t.setStyle(GRID_STYLE)
story.append(t)

doc = SimpleDocTemplate('mydoc.pdf', pagesize=landscape(letter), topMargin=50)
doc.build(story)
```

[image]